# How to enter an enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: loop with xcode debugger?

Tags: xcode, debugging

When I am in debugging mode and I am running my program "step-by-step", `Xcode` does not enter into the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` loops.

My breakpoint is before this loop and beginning from this breakpoint, I would like to execute step-by-step my program. But, when it comes to

```
// When I step-by-step execute
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // it never goes here
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
}] ;
// but goes directly there
```

it automatically goes after the loop.

Why is it so? Is there a way (other that putting a explicite breakpoint in the loop) not to overgo the loop?

Comment: This is a very nice article covering the problem (which is basically a nightmare): http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/block-debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way (other that putting a explicite breakpoint in the loop)
>   not to overgo the loop?

I would say no.
Put a breakpoint inside your block.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If `array.count == 0` it will not enter into the block.
2. Are you clicking the "Step Into" as opposed to the "Step Over" button? https://www.evernote.com/shard/s135/sh/15b5b74a-ff99-4959-9b99-97b2a9ce9e95/c9b5ef45b2a7ba7044abfa9a12f077a7

Comment: Even with "Step Into", it does not work: the debugger is not going into the block.